# What is a single wry "laugh" called?

Tags: single-word-requests

I put laugh in quotes because the thing I'm referring to is less a laugh and more a short burst of sound, for lack of a term I hope answerers can come up with. **I'm looking for a word meaning a single wry or mocking “chuckle” that you might hear with the interjection *ha* or *bah.*** It'll be used in a sentence like this:

> " 'You, help me?' he [verbal form of desired word].”

The word must convey a sense of disbelief or contempt; for lack of a better term, you could call it [*bah*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bah)ing , which would denote the act of making a short sound with the tone of exclaiming “bah!”

***If the word doesn't match the definition either very, very closely or exactly, please don't list it as an answer.***

Comment: Please do not use the site as a thesaurus. I have defended and upvoted your questions more than once but by now you really should follow the minimal guidelines. Where is the research/effort? Where is the sample sentence?

Comment: @Mari-LouA The sample sentence was provided at the end of my question. Please refer to it.

Comment: From Online Oxford: chuckle, chortle,  giggle, titter, snigger, snicker, cackle, mock, deride, scoff at, sneer, smirk, ...

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I thought about "scoff" too, but...well, see [here.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/467610/is-a-scoff-a-sound-one-makes-or-is-it-merely-a-gibe)

Comment: @Mari-LouA Obviously, none of those fit the defintion I listed.

Comment: Obviously? Then include them in the question, and explain why they do not fit because just now you received an answer "snicker" which is in that very list I posted. And you're going to get plenty of others that come from a similar list.

Comment: @Mari-LouA No, I will not. I listed a very specific definition of the word I want. If answerers do not read my question fully, that is not my responsibilty. "Snicker" does not match my definition for the word I am looking for. I specifically asked for a word meaning "a single wry or mocking 'chuckle' that you might hear with the word *ha.*"

Comment: Now I’m a bit confused. In your recent edits, you’ve added that one might call it _bah’ing_ colloquially, but _bah_ **does not in any way indicate a laugh** and so is very obviously not an answer to your question. It indicates disdain and contempt, but no laugh.

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/440537

Comment: Please avoid giving answers and debating in the comment thread. The comment thread is reserved for *helping to improve the post*: friendly clarifying questions, suggestions for improving the question, relevant but transient information, and explanations of your actions.

Comment: OP please [edit] to add details of research you’ve done, especially solutions you’ve already rejected, and why. See the [tag:single-word-requests] tag info for full requirements a word/phrase request must meet to stay open: https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info

Comment: Please stay respectful and kind even when others do not. If a situation makes it hard to act kindly, stop posting. Instead, flag harmful behavior to alert moderators. More information: [Expected Behavior](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/behavior), [Code of Conduct](https://english.stackexchange.com/conduct).

Answer (score 5):

The word is "**snort**". It is sometimes considered a form of laughter showing incredulity and contempt.

> 'You, help me?' he **snorted**.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/snort

https://www.vocabulary.com/lists/132978

Comment: Another OP question today asked about the word "scoff" in a similar way.  It might also work:  https://wikidiff.com/laugh/scoff

Answer (score 4):

**Snicker** might work in your example

> to laugh in a covert or partly suppressed manner

[Definition from Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/snicker)

Comment: Snicker is US only.

Comment: I've heard it used in the UK as well, although snigger may be more common.

Comment: Answerer: I downvoted because this word, in no way, fits the definition I provided in my question.

Comment: A snicker is a polysyllabic snort. Both are phonosemantically coherent with [the `SN-` assonance](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/sn.pdf).

Comment: @JohnLawler thank you for providing the link, very interesting

Answer (score 2):

The noise you describe is a **bark of derision**.

[Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bark+of+derision&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbark%20of%20derision%3B%2Cc0) shows that it's a phrase in reasonably common usage, but looking up the meaning as one idiom is proving difficult.

There's "bark" as a noun from [Collins](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/bark):

> 1. the loud abrupt usually harsh or gruff cry of a dog or any of certain other animals
> 2. a similar sound, such as one made by a person, gun, etc

and as a verb:

> to say or shout in a brusque, peremptory, or angry tone

Which covers the abrupt sound you describe.

And "derision" from [Collins](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/derision)

> The act of ridiculing or laughing at someone or something.

Although this phrase closely matches your definition of the single, short vocalisation, it is difficult to use it with your example as it is. Your example implies a word that is equivalent to "said" where the character is saying the words. You could use "barked derisively", but instead I'd phrase it:

> "You? Help me?". He gave a **bark of derision**.

Comment: I think I would propitiate someone who barked with derision by offering them a bone.

Comment: This is the closest so far, but is there perhaps a more concise term?